# How to add master page after content page

Tags: c#, asp.net

this is my newly added master page:

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Feedback.master.cs" Inherits="Login.Feedback" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head runat="server">
    <title>Untitled Page</title>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    <style type="text/css">
        .style1
        {
            width: 100%;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <table class="style1">
            <tr>
                <td height="166">
                    <asp:AdRotator ID="AdRotator1" runat="server" DataSourceID="XmlDataSource1" />
                    <asp:XmlDataSource ID="XmlDataSource1" runat="server" 
                        DataFile="~/App_Data/AdRotator.xml"></asp:XmlDataSource></td>
                   <td> <img alt="Welcome to Teachers Evaluation System" src="Images/welcome.png" 
                        style="width: 662px; height: 166px" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td valign="top">
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="bodyContent" runat="server">

        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

And this is my login page. I want it to derive from Master. What changes do I need to make? It's giving a lot of errors. Also, I don't want to add any code to Master File - should I keep `Feedback.Master.cs` and `Feedback.Master.Designer`

```
<%@ Page Language="C#"  AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Login.aspx.cs" Inherits="Login._Default" %>


<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">


<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head runat="server">
    <title>Home Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" 
            onselectedindexchanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged">
            <asp:ListItem>Administrator</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>Student</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>Faculty</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>Head of Department</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />

        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="User Name"></asp:Label>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <br />
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <br />
        <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Password"></asp:Label>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" TextMode="Password"></asp:TextBox>
&nbsp;<br />
        <br />
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" onclick="Button2_Click" Text="Connect" 
            Width="79px" />
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" onclick="Button1_Click" Text="Login" 
            Width="70px" />

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please don't shout. I've edited out the caps but I think you need to put more effort into your question as it's unclear - eg What error(s) and where are they occurring?

Comment: its saying that this line cant be inside content placeholder and <td> <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >

Comment: and when i ran it it didnt display login page but gave an error i havnt saved it i reversed all the changes and posted plain code here

Answer (score 0):

In your login page, change your `<body>` tag to `<asp:Content runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="bodyContent">`.

Then remove everything above and below that, and add `MasterPageFile="~/Feedback.master` to your `@Page` directive.

Comment: i have done these changes its giving this error: Compiler Error Message: CS0426: The type name 'Feedback' does not exist in the type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.Login'  SOURCE ERROR: Line 139:        [TemplateContainer(typeof(Login.Feedback))]

Comment: AND 3 ERRORS IN ERROR WINDOW: 1- Warning 2 Validation (XHTML 1.0 Transitional): Content is not supported outside 'script' or 'asp:content' regions. C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\web\Login\Login\Login.aspx 7 2 Login                  2-Warning 3 Validation (XHTML 1.0 Transitional): Element 'body' occurs too few times. C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\web\Login\Login\Login.aspx 7 2 Login
       3RD ERROR: Warning 4 Validation (XHTML 1.0 Transitional): Element 'form' cannot be nested within element 'html'. C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\web\Login\Login\Login.aspx 12 6 Login

Comment: Sorry - you should remove your form tag as well (since the form tag is already in master page). Make sure you get the path to Feedback.master correct (use the URL picker).

Comment: i have done the said changes the only error its giving now is :Compiler Error Message: CS0426: The type name 'Feedback' does not exist in the type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.Login'

Comment: @AngelChoco - Is your project name "Login"?